# RabbitMQ Management Viewing Queues or Exchanges result in Object Not Found

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

We are running the Helm version of RabbitMQ from `stable/rabbitmq`.

We are creating Exchanges and Queues onto the default vhost.

However when we try and view the exchanges or queues through the managemnet console we get an Object Not Found error.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Matt

[image: Screengrab]

Comment: Do you see the expected output if you run `rabbitmqctl list_queues`?